# Constructing Hamiltonian in Matlab using position and momentum operator

Tags: matlab, matrix, physics, equation

I'm trying to construct the position and momentum operators in order to calculate the Hamiltonian of a harmonic oscillator in MATLAB, but I am uncertain if they way I'm doing it is correct.

For the ladder operators I have this code:

```
D=25;
Np=D+1;
n=1:D;
a=diag(sqrt(1:D),1);
ad=a';
```

Then, the momentum and position operators are given by:

[image]

which, in code I have done like this:

```
    hbar = 1;
    m=0.1;
    omega = 1;
    p = -1i*sqrt((hbar*m*omega)/2)*(a-ad);
    x = sqrt(hbar/(2*m*omega))*(a+ad);
```

There are two way of constructing the Hamiltonian which are

[image]
[image]

In code, I have constructed the Hamiltonian as:

```
H = p^2/(2*m)+(1/2)*m*omega*x^2
H1 = hbar*omega*(ad*a + 1/2)
```

but I get two different values for the Hamiltonian. Is this the correct way of constructing the momentum and position operators, and the Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab, `(ad*a + 1/2)` means `ad*a` plus `1/2*ones(size(ad*a))`, i.e., `1/2*ones(D+1,D+1)`.  You probably wanted `(ad*a + 1/2*eye(D+1))`, adding the `1/2` only on the diagonal.  Then the two forms will match (except for the final row/column where you cut off the matrix).

Comment: thank you, this does give me the same main diagonal for both Hamiltonians, but I keep getting values on either side of the main diagonal for `H = p^2/(2*m)+(1/2)*m*omega*x^2`, whereas for H1 I just get a matrix with only a mian diagonal. I'm not sure if that's what I am supposed to be finding, or if there is a mistake somewhere that I can't see

Comment: Those off-diagonal entries are numerically insignificant (around 10^-15).  Matlab is doing standard double-precision floating-point arithmetic (about 15 digits of numeric precision), so that magnitude of rounding error is par for the course.